# What does "Illegal Class Literal" mean?

Tags: java, ide, drjava

Just started using DrJava, and I'm getting an Illegal Class Literal error when I try to run my code. My code compiles, and no issue arises until runtime. Even just the following leads to the error when I run 'java Percolation(5)' in the interaction terminal.

```
public class Percolation {
    public Percolation(int N)  {
        System.out.println(N);
    }    
}
```

I couldn't find anything on Google; any ideas what could be going on here? I feel like I'm missing something stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `main` method?

Comment: Actually `java Percolation(5)` is never going to work, because you can't have a java class called `Percolation(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your program, you have to call a starting or main method. This method as to be `public static void` and it has to take VarArgs or an Array for your arguments:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // in here, you can do stuff like calling other functions, or creating objects

    // no checks, just demo how to use the args:
    Perlocation p = new Perlocation(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
}
```

Then you can call your program via

```
java Percolation 5
```

Comment: Careful with Integer#decode, though. It does funny things with leading zeros. I'd use Integer#valueOf or Integer#parseInt

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In the past I've used BlueJ for courses, which breaks things up, and I guess hides away the main method. Thus, I've never come across a main method before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `main` method in your class to be able to run it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Then if you want to pass an argument to the main method, you call it via

```
java Percolation 5
```

not

```
java Percolation(5)
```